# c++ force array declaration without giving parameters

Tags: c++, arrays, ros

I'm currently trying to program an array of objects in a c++ program. However it keeps giving me errors when trying to create the arrays. 
So on top of my code I have the following code:

```
#define sensNumber 4
ros::Publisher pub_range2 [sensNumber];
```

this gives the error:

```
multisone2.ino:19:38: error: no matching function for call to ‘ros::Publisher::Publisher()’
```

So it's trying to call the constructor for Publisher, why? And how do I stop it?

Now I know this can also be done with Vectors but I'm trying to optimize the code esp. for reading speed so I would rather avoid vectors(yes I know that it remains linair but accessing this array represents a significant portion of my code).

Comment: That's weird - according to [the documentation](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1Publisher.html), `ros::Publisher` *has* a public default constructor, so that should work. You might be missing something else.

Answer (score 2):

As you're trying to stack-allocate `sensNumber` instances of `ros::Publisher`, the default constructor *must* be called.

An alternative would be to allocate an array of pointers to `ros::Publisher`. Better still, an array of `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Is it also possible to force the same parameter on all instances and then later on change them into what I want them to be?

Comment: There are indeed ways (placement new for example, but please forget I mentioned that immediately after your reading it) but, really you should be using an stl container to do this.

Comment: I'm asking both because I really want to use it more "java style" and because this is running on an arduino which is not quite capable of handling what I'm doing so I'm looking for situations like pointers that need not be pointers and stuff like that.

Comment: @Thijser You can provide your own parameter less constructor with any default initialization you want.

Comment: So that would look something like ros::Publisher * pub = new ros::Publisher[sizeof(pub_range)*sensNumber]( "/ultrasound", &range_msg);? that still gives me an error error: parenthesized initializer in array new [-fpermissive] is there an easy fix for that? and @atoMerz I would rather not mess with the ross code at this point.

Comment: @Thijser You can also use a simple loop. Declare your array of pointers, loop over its elements, and instantiate each of them.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare an array of c++ objects you're actually instantiating each element. This means that the default parameterless constructor is called for each array element. If you don't want to instantiate all elements when declaring your array, you should declare an array of pointers instead and then initialize each element whenever required.